# Merge pandas rows based on values and NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this :

```
ID  VALUE1  VALUE2  VALUE3
1   NaN     [ab,c]  Good
1   google  [ab,c]  Good
2   NaN     [ab,c1] NaN
2   First   [ab,c1] Good1
2   First   [ab,c1]  
3   NaN     [ab,c]  Good
```

Requirement is :
ID is the key. I have 3 rows for ID 2. So, I need to merge two rows into 1 row such that I have valid values (excluding Nulls and spaces) for all the columns.

My expected output is:

```
ID  VALUE1  VALUE2  VALUE3
1   google      [ab,c]  Good
2   First       [ab,c1] Good1
3   NaN     [ab,c]  Good
```

Do we have any pandas function to achieve this or should I have to seperate the data into two or more dataframes and process for merging based on NaN/spaces?
Thanks for your help

Comment: why is `NaN     [ab,c]  Good` in the output? It matches with the google row for 'Good' & [ab,c]

Comment: Can you please explain what you want to do? It's not clear if you want to pull the first elemet from each `VALUE1` group or a random one... As it stands, `df.groupby('VALUE1').first()` would be a valid solution.

Comment: I have added details.

Comment: `df.groupby('ID').first()` ?

Comment: Its doable, just a minute. I'm not putting '[ ]' into the dataframe because this means something else in python.

Answer (score 1):

Micheal G has a more elegant solution above.
Here is my more time consuming and amateur approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1,1,2,2,2,3],
        "V1": [np.nan,'google',np.nan,'First','First',np.nan],
        "V2": [['ab','c'],['ab','c'],['ab','c1'],['ab','c1'],['ab','c1'],['ab','c']],
        "V3": ['Good','Good',np.nan,np.nan,'Good1','Good']
    })
```

```
uniq = df.ID.unique() #Get the unique values in ID
df = df.set_index(['ID']) #Since we are try find the rows with the least amount of nan's.
#Setting the index by ID is going to make our future statements faster and easier.
newDf = pd.DataFrame()
for i in uniq: #Running the loop per unique value in column ID
    temp = df.loc[i]
    if(isinstance(temp, pd.Series)): #if there is only 1 row with the i, add that row to out new DataFrame
        newDf = newDf.append(temp)
    else:
        NonNanCountSeries = temp.apply(lambda x: x.count(), axis=1)
        #Get the number of non-nan's in the per each row. It is given in list.
        NonNanCountList = NonNanCountSeries.tolist()
        newDf = newDf.append(temp.iloc[NonNanCountList.index(max(NonNanCountList))])
        #Let's break this down.
        #Find the max in out nanCountList: max(NonNanCountList))
        #Find the index of where the max is. Paraphrased: get the row number with the  
        #most amount of non-nan's: NonNanCountList.index(max(NonNanCountList))
        #Get the row by passing the index into temp.iloc
        #Add the row to newDf and update newDf

print(newDf)
```

Which should return:

```
       V1        V2     V3
1  google   [ab, c]   Good
2   First  [ab, c1]  Good1
3     NaN   [ab, c]   Good
```

Comment: Innovative solution. +1

Comment: I am getting the output `  VALUE1 VALUE2 VALUE3
1    NaN    abc   Good` But expected is : `  VALUE1 VALUE2 VALUE3
1    Google   abc   Good`. Input used : data = {'ID' : [1,1,2,2,2,3], 'VALUE1':[np.NaN,'Google',np.NaN, 'First', 'First',np.NaN], 
        'VALUE2':['abc', np.NaN, 'abc1', 'abc1', 'abc1', 'abc'], 'VALUE3': ['Good', 'Good',np.NaN, 'Good1', '0', 'Good']} 
df_w = pd.DataFrame(data)

Comment: Hey Madan
I have misunderstood your question. I'm sorry. 
What you are describing is not possible in Pandas unless you treat each cell as a list. Example:data = {'ID' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,3], 'VALUE1':['Amazon',np.NaN,'Google',np.NaN, 'First', 'First',np.NaN], 'VALUE2':[np.NaN,'abc', np.NaN, 'abc1', 'abc1', 'abc1', 'abc'], 'VALUE3': [np.NaN,'Good', 'Good',np.NaN, 'Good1', '0', 'Good']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
Your output for ID 1(if treating each cell as list) would be:  VALUE1 VALUE2 VALUE3 ['Amazon','Google], abc, Good.

Let me know if you still need help and I can change the above snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Note, I capitalised Google.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'ID' : [1,1,2,2,2,3], 'VALUE1':['NaN','Google','NaN', 'First', 'First','NaN'], 'VALUE2':['abc', 'abc', 'abc1', 'abc1', 'abc1', 'abc'], 'VALUE3': ['Good', 'Good', 'NaN', 'Good1', '0', 'Good']}        
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_ = df.replace('NaN', np.NaN).fillna('zero', inplace=False)
df2 = df_.sort_values(['VALUE1', 'ID'])
mask = df2.ID.duplicated()
print (df_[~mask])
```

**Output**

```
   ID  VALUE1 VALUE2 VALUE3
1   1  Google    abc   Good
3   2   First   abc1  Good1
5   3    zero    abc   Good
```

Finally, just be aware the tilda character (~) in the mask is essential

Comment: The Null values can be present in any column. Can be in Value2, Value3. Also, my original dataframe shape is (109444, 9).

Comment: Just use fillna in this case I've swtiched NaN to 'zero'

Comment: Tried :
data = {'ID' : [1,1,2,2,2,3], 'VALUE1':[np.NaN,'Google',np.NaN, 'First', 'First',np.NaN], 'VALUE2':['abc', np.NaN, 'abc1', 'abc1', 'abc1', 'abc'], 'VALUE3': ['Good', 'Good',np.NaN, 'Good1', '0', 'Good']}        
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = df.sort_values('VALUE1').sort_values('ID').fillna('zero', inplace=True)
mask = df2.ID.duplicated()
print (df[~mask])

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ID'

Comment: Also for  data = {'ID' : [1,1,2,2,2,3], 'VALUE1':[np.NaN,'Google',np.NaN, 'First', 'First',np.NaN], 'VALUE2':['abc', np.NaN, 'abc1', 'abc1', 'abc1', 'abc'], 'VALUE3': ['Good', 'Good',np.NaN, 'Good1', '0', 'Good']} df = pd.DataFrame(data) . The expected output is : `   ID  VALUE1 VALUE2 VALUE3
   1  Google   abc Good
  2   First   abc1  Good1
  3    zero    abc   Good`. But I am getting zero for column VALUE1 for the ID1

Comment: Although I can't reproduce the error (I get the expected output), I've modified the sort for a "nested sort" approach which is more formal.